# Difficulty Connecting To Hard Drive Via USB SATA Cable

Tags: hard-drive, data-recovery, sata

I have a one year old 1TB Western Digital hard drive from which I am trying to recover some files.  The drive had Windows 7 on it, installed from a factory disk.

I am attempting to connect to my Windows 7 desktop via a USB to SATA "APRICORN" cord. I used this adapter previously, but it won't seem to work now with this hard drive on several different computers. The hard drive and the cord both show up under device manager -> disk drives. Under Devices and Printers, only the cord shows up, and I don't see the hard drive under `Computer` like I did with the other drives I have used this cord for.  The drive fails to initialize as both MBR and GPT.

How can I recover user files from the drive?

Comment: Please [edit] and add paragraphs and formatting for readability

Comment: @Paul Thank you for pointing that out, is this any better?

Comment: @fixer1234 better? :) Sorry I haven't been on an SE for a while.

Comment: Are you trying to just read the drive while connected externally or boot it?  Have you tried an internal SATA connection on your desktop machine?  Do you have access to a different USB adapter or enclosure (they're very inexpensive to just buy as a test, as is an extra SATA cable)?  Can you verify that the Apricorn is still working with another drive?  If you can see the drive, you should be able to copy files off (or use recovery software like Recuva if your files aren't visible).  If you can't see the drive, there isn't much you can do with software.

Comment: @fixer1234 I am just trying to read the drive while it is connected externally. I don't feel comfortable using the desktop's internal SATA. I'm pretty sure the cord still works, I don't have a drive I can test with on me at the moment, I do not have access to another enclosure, I would like to avoid buying one if I can. I can only see the drive in device manager, however, I cant see it as another disk.

Comment: Does the drive spin up?  The best and simplest test would be to try connecting the drive internally (there's no incremental risk over connecting via USB).  You could add it as an additional SATA drive, or even replace the desktop's drive just to see if it will boot.  Not booting could be other problems with the drive, but if you connect it as a second SATA drive and it isn't recognized, that will tell you whether the drive has problems.  If it does, the next step would be to see if they are correctable.  If you can see it when it's connected internally, you should be able to get your files.

Comment: @fixer1234 It does spin up. I can consider connecting it to the SATA port but I would prefer not too. Is there a way to diagnose and fix what is going on with the USB to SATA cord?

Comment: The OS needs to see the drive to do anything.  If the adapter isn't working, either it's bad or the drive is bad, which could be either drive failure (which would be unusual in only a year), or corruption.  That's a lot of possibilities.  A SATA connection eliminates the adapter from the equation.  It also might be worth running a partition utility just to see what it says about the drive.  If it's corrupted, it should still show up.

Comment: @fixer1234 Thank you for the reply, sorry I didnt see it sooner, I tried this a while ago using a different connector, it showed the partitions (and I think their size) in the utility but did not show contents it looked like it was having difficulty seeing what was on them, I remember thinking about why that might be and never testing the theory. But I don't remember, thats where I left off.